# mysqli_fetch_array not showing results correct

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I’m rather new to both MySQL and PHP. But I am trying to list my results correct with from my database. But only get some results.

This is my SQL, and when I try it direct to the database I get the result I want.

```
$sql = "SELECT ItemRelation.ItemRelTo, ItemRelation.Item, Items.CatID, Items.ItemID,             
Items.Title, Items.Image, Items.Desc, Items.TimeStamp
FROM Items
INNER JOIN ItemRelation
ON ItemRelation.ItemRelTo=Items.ItemID
WHERE ItemRelation.Item = " . $filterbyitem;
```

So it’s when I am trying to list my result with a mysqli_fetch_array I don't get the same

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ItemID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Item'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row2['CatID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row2['Title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><img src="Image/',$row2['Image'],'"></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row2['Desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row2['TimeStamp'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

It list the result from ItemID and Item but the rest will not show. Is there anyone that can see any problem by doing this? I have listed my results like this before but not whit this SQL commando when I read from several tables.

Comment: Looks like a too way localized not a real question which has absolutely nothing to do with mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: Change `$row2` to `$row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change row2 to row and it solves your problem

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ItemID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Item'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['CatID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><img src="Image/',$row['Image'],'"></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['TimeStamp'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```